# Is there a way to change a conditional using a Try/Catch/Finally block in Powershell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, try-catch, try-catch-finally, powershell-5.1

Is there a way to do something similar to what is listed below:

```
    Try{
        if(<#conditional here#>)
    }
    catch[ArgumentOutOfRangeException]{
    }
    Finally{
        #Set if statement to false, and run else statement
    }
```

This is what the code currently looks like, imagine this inside of a standard runspacePool:

```
try {

            $substring = $fileString.Substring(19, 2)

        } 
        catch [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException] {

            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $errorOccurred = $true
            Copy-Item -Path "$($copyFilePath)\$($_)" -Destination $copyFileBadNameDestination -Recurse -Force -Verbose
            continue

        }

        if($substring -match '[0-9][0-9]'){
    
            if(<#Filters that rely on the above if statement#>){

                Copy-Item -Path "$($copyFilePath)\$($_)" -Destination $copyFileBadNameDestination -Recurse -Force -Verbose

            }
        } 
        else{

            Copy-Item -Path "$($copyFilePath)\$($_)" -Destination $copyFileBadNameDestination -Recurse -Force -Verbose

        }
```

The problem is I was previously using an if statement to do this and it made the code extremely inefficient, this in theory would make it so instead of looping through every file before managing them anyways, I could just pick out files that don't meet the file name length requirement that would cause an error with a substring, and still cast them to the else statement where they belong, instead of them getting skipped over.

Comment: You.can do `$Condition = Try { <#conditional here#> } Catch { ... } Finaly { $False }; If ($Condition) { ...` ( not sure what exact logic you're looking for.)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, turns out the error wasn't my logic, it was that the entire try block was running in a runspace so it wasn't capturing the error in the first place

Comment: @RalphWarner So... problem solved? If so, please post an answer below

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , well yes and no... I know the answer to the question asked, but I still can't get the code running. Since it is within a runspace I can't seem to get the try block to see the error that is occuring.

Comment: Is it possible for you to produce a smaller version of your code that reproduces the issue? It's near impossible to help you troubleshoot based on "it is within a runspace" - all PowerShell code runs in a runspace :)

Comment: Not really, I could spam characters after the code, but Overflow will probably flag me for that too. Annoying as hell. As far as runspaces though, I was referring to launching a runspace pool and running the code on a separate thread from the main thread.

Comment: No, I didn't mean "post your 1 million line script", I meant: can you write a simpler version of your code that has the same problem? An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm aware, but to replicate the issue it requires spinning up a runspace pool, creating an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, and handling said exception. As it was the site was getting upset when I tried to put in merely 40 lines of code when I thought the runspaces had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please [try adding your code again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76466642/edit) - 40 lines definitely shouldn't be a problem. I managed write a script that executes you described [code in 27 lines](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/db6a2ad8e4f1cbf5ac322d8dc42a257f), is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think that's similar if it's producing the same issue, I'll try uploading again.

Comment: Why all this error handling? Why not just check `if ($fileString.Length -ge 21){ ... }`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this is what I was doing before, but it made the code incredibly slow since I had to loop through every file, the point of my code is to optimize a previously slow process.

Comment: Trust me, exception-driven programming is going to be MUCH slower than a simple `if($string.Length){ ... }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I mean it's worth a shot at least, in the case of the try block it should only proc when a file comes in thats too short, otherwise the code will run at the speed without the try block even being involved(I think). Which means instead of 3M45s we're looking at 20s. The try block will very rarely ever actually be set off, which is why the if statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just _having_ the `try`/`catch` block will slow it down. Here's a comparison over a generated dataset with a 20% failure rate: https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/f4d8c0e8a71c938b525ecbc0e8c3610b - `try`/`catch` approach is ~9-10 times slower

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Even if the failure rate were hovering around .01% or lower?

Comment: The ratio will be way lower, but `try`/`catch` will still be slower overall.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Should I try a switch case then? if the int = 27 run the normal case otherwise just immediately copy the file? or will that still be slower than the if?

Comment: No, just use `if($string.Length -ge 21) { ... }else { ... }`.

Comment: Damn, unfortunate. It feels incredibly slow, as if there should be some faster way than checking every file.